# Grid using float left is leaving gaps

Tags: html, css

I have a simple css which floats elements to the left and creates a table structure. I wanted the table to be dynamic, being able to add a column if the user expands the browser so I have used elements that float left. However it sometimes does not work. I have created a jsfiddle that shows the scenario.

It works for one column, two columns but it does not work for three columns and it leaves a gap.

I cannot understand why it is leaving that gap. Here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/workmonitored/hgt9Lp5n/12/

html

```
<div style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:15px">
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Flows 1:</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <input type="text" name="DetailProjectReportingPeriodDetailEditUI.employeeName">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Flows 2:</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <input type="text" name="DetailProjectReportingPeriodDetailEditUI.employeeName">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Flows 3:</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <input type="text" name="DetailProjectReportingPeriodDetailEditUI.employeeName">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Flows 4:</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <input type="text" name="DetailProjectReportingPeriodDetailEditUI.employeeName">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Employee Name:</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <input type="text" name="DetailProjectReportingPeriodDetailEditUI.employeeName" style="width: 90%">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Affiliation</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <select>
            <option value="1">Member</option>
            <option value="1">Member Spouse</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Job Title</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <select>
            <option value="1">Mr smith</option>
            <option value="1">Mrs smith</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Classification</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <select>
            <option value="1">Worker Bee</option>
            <option value="1">Grasshoper Initiate</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Hire Date</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <input type="text" id="hiredate" name="DetailProjectReportingPeriodDetailEditUI.hireDateStr" style="width: 90%">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Job Status</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <input type="text" id="hiredate" name="DetailProjectReportingPeriodDetailEditUI.hireDateStr" style="width: 90%">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Pay Scale</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <input name="DetailProjectReportingPeriodDetailEditUI.payScale" size="12">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <div class="description">Notes</div>
    <div class="userOutput">
        <textarea rows="1" name="DetailProjectReportingPeriodDetailEditUI.note" style="width: 99%"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both; height:5px"></div>
<div class="keepTogether">
    <button id="saveReportingPeriodDetail">Save</button>
    <button id="cancelReportingPeriodDetail">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

css

```
.description {
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
}
.userOutput {
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
}
.userInput {
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
}
.keepTogether {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.keepTogether select {
    width: 220px;
}
.keepTogether input {
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `margin` on `input` and `select` elements to `0` sorted out the issue also.

```
.keepTogether input {
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hgt9Lp5n/13/

Comment: Wrong answer: look at your fiddle.. problem still exists